# Expand all nodes in a TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a treeview bound to collection of objects using MVVM. However, i need to expand all the nodes of the treeview by default.
Tried using style:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
 <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

But that does not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That style works for me, where did you place it?

You might want to assign it explicitly as the `TreeView`'s [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx).

Comment: Works fine using ItemContainerStyle.. Thanks